# Objective-C Error Handling with Enum like in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, enums

I am just getting familiar with Objective-C as my primary language is Swift. And I can't find out the best way to handle error cases with Objective-c enums as I could do the same using Swift.

For example in Swift I can handle error with convenient enum like that:

```
import Foundation

public enum ErrorCases: Error, LocalizedError {
    case invalidURL(String)
    case JSONStringConversionError(String)
    case JSONStringifyError(Any?)
    case hashArrayCastError(Any)

    public var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .invalidURL(let url): return "Invalid URL: \(url)."
        case .JSONStringConversionError(let jsonString): return "Cannot convert string to JSON, string: \(jsonString)."
        case .JSONStringifyError(let data): return "Cannot stringify JSON dictionary with 'Any' data to a string, data: \(String(describing: data))."
        case .hashArrayCastError(let hashArray): return "Cannot cast JSON with '#' key to an arrray of 'Any' objects from massage, JSON: \(hashArray)."
        }
    }
}
```

And now I can use that enum like that:

```
if error != nil {
    self.onError(error: ErrorCases.invalidURL(self.mUrl))
}
```

Could you recommend the better way to implement the same error handling but using Objective-C! 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objC, you can't really do the same thing as enums cannot have associated values.
Error handling in objC is mainly done with NSError object.
In your case I recommand creating an enum :

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ErrorCaseType) {
    ErrorCaseTypeInvalidURL,
    ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringConversionError,
    ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringifyError,
    ErrorCaseTypeHashArrayCastError
};
```

then upon error, create an error object:

```
error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.myapp.mydomain" 
                                code: ErrorCaseTypeInvalidURL
                            userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString(@"Oops...", nil)}];
```

When receiving an error you can then access to `[error code]` value and check it against your enum or/and display the `[error localizedDescription]` text.

You can find more about error object here : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC

Answer (score 0):

The better solution I can think of is something like this:

`ErrorCase.h`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ErrorCaseType) {
    ErrorCaseTypeInvalidURL,
    ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringConversionError,
    ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringifyError,
    ErrorCaseTypeHashArrayCastError
};

@interface ErrorCase : NSObject

@property (readonly, assign) ErrorCaseType errorType;
@property (readonly, assign) NSString *URL;
@property (readonly, assign) NSString *jsonString;
@property (readonly, assign) id data;
@property (readonly, assign) id hashArray;

+ (instancetype) InvalidURL:(NSString *)URL;
+ (instancetype) JSONStringConversionError:(NSString *)jsonString;
+ (instancetype) JSONStringifyError:(id)data;
+ (instancetype) HashArrayCastError:(id)hashArray;

@end
```

and `ErrorCase.m`

```
@interface ErrorCase ()

@property (readwrite, assign) ErrorCaseType errorType;
@property (readwrite, assign) NSString *URL;
@property (readwrite, assign) NSString *jsonString;
@property (readwrite, assign) id data;
@property (readwrite, assign) id hashArray;

@end

@implementation ErrorCase

+ (instancetype) InvalidURL:(NSString *)URL {
    ErrorCase *error = [[ErrorCase alloc] init];
    error.URL = URL;
    error.errorType = ErrorCaseTypeInvalidURL;
    return error;
}

+ (instancetype) JSONStringConversionError:(NSString *)jsonString {
    ErrorCase *error = [[ErrorCase alloc] init];
    error.jsonString = jsonString;
    error.errorType = ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringConversionError;
    return error;
}

+ (instancetype) JSONStringifyError:(id)data {
    ErrorCase *error = [[ErrorCase alloc] init];
    error.data = data;
    error.errorType = ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringifyError;
    return error;
}

+ (instancetype) HashArrayCastError:(id)hashArray {
    ErrorCase *error = [[ErrorCase alloc] init];
    error.hashArray = hashArray;
    error.errorType = ErrorCaseTypeHashArrayCastError;
    return error;
}

@end
```

You can use it like this

```
ErrorCase *errorCase = [ErrorCase InvalidURL:@"https://example.com"];

switch (errorCase.errorType) {
    case ErrorCaseTypeInvalidURL: NSLog(@"Invalid URL %@", errorCase.URL); break;
    case ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringConversionError: NSLog(@"Conversion Error %@", errorCase.jsonString); break;
    case ErrorCaseTypeJSONStringifyError: NSLog(@"Stringify Error %@", errorCase.data); break;
    case ErrorCaseTypeHashArrayCastError: NSLog(@"Cast Error %@", errorCase.hashArray); break;
}
```

Comment: It might look ugly in the implementation, but the interface is not that bad.

Comment: Never use `assign` properties with objects unless you really, _really_ know what you're doing! As @clemens said, these may cause dangling pointers. The ones for strings should all be `copy`, the ones for `id` should be `strong` or `retain`.